# Regex How to replace a $value without replacing any other numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am totally new to regex.

I am pulling values off a number of select drop downs where there a lot of unselected values. Here is a sample of the raw data:

```
NoneNoneNoneBP #15 Plain Felt 36" | $10.00NoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNone
```

All the "none" values are empty selects.

I need to strip out all the garbage data leaving only the name of the product ie **"BP #15 Plain Felt 36"**

That is to say the $, the value all the "none" and the "|" all have to go.

I'm doing ok, except that my regex strips out the numeric digits in the product name as well as the dollar value. ie **15** and **36**.

I don't know how to isolate the digits relating to the $value without impacting the digits relating to the product description.  Any advice ? tks !

This is what I have so far:

```
 var materials_replace = materials.replace(/None|\||[\$(\d)(\.)]/g,'');
```

Comment: looks like you're close...you don't want to match individual characters (which is what `[...]` does), you want to match the sequence $##.## - any dollar sign followed by 1 or more digits possibly followed by a decimal followed by one or more digits...that sequence ends up looking more like what you're using to match "None" (i.e. the sequence of chars N-o-n-e)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first two parts look right (although do you care about the whitespace surrounding the |?)

```
None
\|
```

the last part would look like

```
\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

\$ - the dollar sign

\d+ - followed by one or more digits

(?:.\d+)? - optionally followed by a decimal plus one or more digits - the (?:..) part just creates a group that isn't 'captured' (although capturing here is insignificant since you're using the regex to match a replacement) - we need to group the `\.\d+` part though to say the group itself is optionally matched (the last ?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all `None` by white space or blank here try this

```js
var valueeee = 'NoneNoneNoneBP #15 Plain Felt 36" | $10.00NoneNoneNoneNoneNoneNone'

var strs = valueeee.replace(/\None/g,'');
var str = valueeee.replace(/\None|\|/g,'');
console.log(str);
console.log(strs);
```